# Xcode - Change development Team without losing CoreData

Tags: swift, xcode

I had a problem with my personal development account so I was forced to use my mother's to develop a very easy app (I don't have anymore the premium account).
Now I would like to go back and use my account but, on my iPhone I have a lot of data saved with Core Data that I don't want to lose.
If I try to install the app simply changing the development team on the simulator everything is ok but on my iPhone I get this error:

```
Details

Unable to install "Test App
"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2021-12-20 17:30:05 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
This application’s application-identifier entitlement does not match that of the installed application. These values must match for an upgrade to be allowed.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402652994
User Info: {
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Couldn't you search for the core data database and copy it and paste it afterwards ?

Comment: looks like you are changing Bundle Identifier, not just Team. As for team, I never tried to use free account, but normally you'd need to transfer the app as explained here: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f

Comment: @Kets is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: @leobartowski Maybe search for "Transferring iOS App's Core Data Storage from One Simulator to Another" And see if this works. I'm working with core data but not that good. Like I can see the database on my Mac and even copy it, so I would assume that you could copy paste it.

Comment: I'll give a look, thanks a lot